# How many types of random variables are there?

Tags: probability-theory

I'm wondering just how many types of random variables are there...

I know of discrete, absolutely continuous, mixed, and finally those with a continuous distribution function but without a density(cantor's function).

What other types of r.v. are there, which do not fit in the previously stated types?

Edit: my definition of r.v. is a measurable function.

Comment: What is your definition of random variable? If it is: "A random variable is a measurable function" then you may classify them by their distributions, and then it is just a matter of classifying probability measures (on $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: @G.Chiusole a measurable function. But then, how many types of probability measures do we have?

Comment: Then I am not sure if there is a nice classification to begin with, as measures are fairly general

Comment: @G.Chiusole a potential answer doesn't have to be exhaustive, then. You can just give all that you know, not listed in the original post.

Comment: There are many types that have been given names. Are you asking for a list of the different "classes" of probability distributions that we mathematicians have come up with over the centuries?

Comment: @Arthur Probably... but since I'm not sure of what classes you're talking about, I can't give you a definitive answer.

Comment: Maybe have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions). The headers give a rough overview which may or may not be exhaustive

Comment: @G.Chiusole all of those are included in the types I've alluded to in the original post... I'm looking for other types.